# Why does the server program not exit?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a fundamental question about Java RMI, I have mostly a C++ background, and there is something I don't get with RMI.

To be clear, I am able to make it work fine, but it's something about the program lifetime.

If I have a toy Java program such as:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println( "start !" );
    }
}
```

when I run it from shell, it prints the message and exits.

If I want to use sockets, then I **need** to have some infinite loop in my server, that will wait for incoming connections, process them, then start over.

```
ServerSocket socketserver = new ServerSocket( port_id );
System.out.println( "server: waiting"  );   

while(true) {
    Socket socket = socketserver.accept(); 
    System.out.println( "server: incoming connection" );
    ... do stuff...
    socket.close();
}
```

Now, say I have an RMI server with the following `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println( "RMI server started !" );
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    Naming.bind( "//localhost/myObject", obj );
    System.out.println( "Done!" );
}
```

Assuming the class `MyObject` can be found, and that everything compiles fine.

If I run this from the shell, then although it **does** print the last message and that is **no infinite loop after that line**, the program **does not** exit.

Questions:

- Does the RMI API implement some hidden infinite loop, thats waits for incoming connections ? Or else what is the explanation?
- How do I programmaticaly terminate the server ? Say if I want it to terminate after "x" seconds?

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169097/) answers the first question, but not the second. Neither does the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html) (unless I missed that ?)

Comment: The Object class is always found in Java. It is the hierarchical parent of all classes

Comment: @Jarrod , thanks, but the other question does not adress my second question, so not entirely a dupe. And mine has (IMHO) a better title...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson , thanks, but the other question does not adress my second question, so not entirely a dupe. And mine has (IMHO) a better title...

Comment: questions should only have one question in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. RMI creates a background non-daemon thread for every port it is listening to. That thread will only exit when all the objects that are exported on its port have been unexported, either explicitly or via DGC.
2. Unexport the remote objects, including the Registry if you started it yourself in the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, great, exactly what I wanted to know. Could you expand `DGC` ? Might be trivial in javaworld, but I come from C++.

Comment: DGC is Distributed Garbage Collection of remote objects, which can happen when no JVM holds a reference to it. For example, if there are no clients and you unbind a remote object from the Registry, after some minutes the remote object will be DGC'd and unexported, so its accept thread can exit, so the JVM can exit, if there are no other remote objects. You can be informed about DGC via the `Unreferenced` interface.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, the reference seems to be this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch4.html

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a thread that listens for client connections and creates worker threads to respond to clients.  When the main thread terminated the joined threads will also terminate.

Comment: Thanks, but thats a bit short for me. You mean I need to go into Java threads even with a single pair of computers ? No simple way ?

Comment: You don't appear to have read the question. It is about RMI, not sockets. RMI already does what you describe, which is the reason for the behaviour. The final sentence is simply untrue.